# Azure function: access a folder structure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

just started testing azure functions to see if it will fit in our application.

What I want is a function like /api/updateToVersion/3.0 where the code will look if there is a folder 3.0 and if there is it will zip the folder and send over as byte[].

But I don't understand where should I keep this folder (which may have multiple files). Azube blob storage (correct me if I am wrong) is for single files. Not folders. 
I have uploaded folder 3.0 to my microsoft azure storage (in Files shares). 
How can I access the from my function?

Answer (score 3):

You can interact with your files using the **[Azure Storage SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage?view=azure-dotnet)**. Unfortunately, you won't be able to simple mount your Azure File Share within your Azure Function.

---

However, I would use **Azure Blob Storage**. Azure Blob Storage uses something like virtual directories where the directory name is *part of the filename*.

e. g. you have a container named *mycontainer* you can have files in there like:

```
/api/updateToVersion/3.0/customers.csv
/api/updateToVersion/3.0/account.txt
```

Now you can retrieve all files that are within `/api/updateToVersion/3.0/` - example:

```
 var directory = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("yourCs").
    CreateCloudBlobClient().
    GetContainerReference("mycontainer").
    GetDirectoryReference(@"/api/updateToVersion/3.0/");
```

Finally iterate over the files and zip / send them.

Answer (score 2):

So after some research I concluded to this:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(webStorageConfigString);
CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("MYFOLDERNAME");
if (!(await share.ExistsAsync()))
  throw new Exception($"No folder found: MYFOLDERNAME");

// Get a reference to the root directory for the share.
CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
CloudFileDirectory mcmUpdateDir = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference("OTHER FOLDER");
```

and so on.
I just post it here for others which have the same questions